# Hbase on EC2 using Whirr. How?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hbase, apache-whirr

I'm trying to create a test cluster on EC2 with Hadoop and Hbase using Whirr.

Following instructions from some sites:

- http://whirr.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/whirr-in-5-minutes.html
- http://www.bigfastblog.com/run-the-latest-whirr-and-deploy-hbase-in-minutes
- http://dal-cloudcomputing.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-set-up-hadoop-and-hbase-together.html

Steps that I did without problems (or that is what I think...):

- Generate ssh keypair with ssh-keygen -t rsa
- Modify hbase recipe with keys, amis, zones, and number of nodes (1 master, 1 datanode)
- Launch cluster

At this point, I see 2 new EC2 instances in my AWS Panel and I can connect trough ssh to both, but I only see this on home:

```
configure-zookeeper_hadoop-namenode_hadoop-jobstracker_hbase-master
```

and

```
configure_hadoop-datanode_hadoop-tasktracker_hbase-regionserver
```

I have tried execute (in another terminal)

```
sh ~/.whirr/hbase/hbase-proxy.sh
```

But at this point, I can't follow any guide (execute hadoop, hbase, whatever).

Comment: Did you set your firewall/ports correctly? I had that problem on EC2, and had to fix that.

Comment: Yes srs2012, I've opened ports in Security Groups, but problem persist.